# Multiple IFrames side by side and center aligned in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

Suppose I have 4 iframes containing affiliate links from amazon, which look something like:

```
<iframe style="width:120px;height:240px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//ws-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&OneJS=1&Operation=GetAdHtml&MarketPlace=GB&source=ss&ref=as_ss_li_til&ad_type=product_link&tracking_id=*****anguage=en_GB&marketplace=amazon&region=GB&placement=*********5&show_border=true&link_opens_in_new_window=true"></iframe>
```

How do I put several side by side and centre aligned horizontally in WordPress classic editor?

I'm using raw HTML. There are so many options I'm overwhelmed, and want the best/simplest solution.

For example, do I wrap them all in a div? If so what styles or build-in classes should I add?

Or maybe add `class="alignleft"` to each iframe, but then how do I centre them horizontally?

It may well be that WordPress now has flexbox, and I should use that?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Wordpress is a content management/blog system it doesn't itself interpret CSS. It's the user's browser that interprets stuff like flex. If you can get the raw HTML into your post then you can try flex in a wrapper div.

Comment: What would be the appropriate rule please? Something like <div style="flex-align">?

Comment: Don't worry. I've got it: `<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;">`